# Adding a WindowStateListener in scala.swing

Tags: java, swing, scala

How do I add a `WindowStateListener` to the reactions for a MainFrame in scala.swing?

None of the classes in `scala.swing.event` seem to be appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with `scala.swing` out of the box (I just grepped the 2.9.1 source for `WindowStateListener` to be sure), but it's very easy to roll your own:

```
import swing._

case class WindowStateChanged(
  override val source: Window,
  oldState: Int,
  newState: Int
) extends event.WindowEvent(source)

trait StateListeningWindow extends Window { outer =>
  this.peer.addWindowStateListener(new java.awt.event.WindowStateListener {
    def windowStateChanged(e: java.awt.event.WindowEvent) {
      publish(WindowStateChanged(outer, e.getOldState, e.getNewState))
    }
  })
}
```

Now just mix in `StateListeningWindow`:

```
object WindowStateDemo extends SimpleSwingApplication {
  def top = new MainFrame with StateListeningWindow {
    import java.awt.Frame._
    reactions += {
      case WindowStateChanged(_, _, ICONIFIED) => // Do something.
      case WindowStateChanged(_, oldState, newState) => // Something else.
    }
  }
}
```

You could also easily wrap up the `java.awt.Frame` constants for something more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks. I may be able to use this technique for other event listeners that I also need (like property change listener).